# How to use if condition(knockout) in html template ? magento 2

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, requirejs

How to use if / else condition in html template file ?

Comment: you have to be more specific than that to get an answer. you can start from here if you want https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/ui_comp_guide/concepts/ui_comp_config_flow_concept.html and see what case fits you best. but maybe you should explain what you need exactly

Comment: I need to call a js function "useShippingAddress" which is in "app/code/Code/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/billing-address.js" file , i want to call this function in the same file but on changing the shipping address from existing options or on click a div.

Answer (score 0):

if condition example.

```
<!-- ko if: useShippingAddress() -->
     //your html code goes here
<!-- /ko -->

<!-- ko ifnot: useShippingAddress() -->
    //your html code goes here
<!-- /ko -->
```